# Toolbar button with cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard is existing?

Tags: ionic-framework, ngx-quill

I should implement a rich text editor on my hybride app (ionic 3).

I'm using ngx-quill. it's working on Chrome (PC)
Unfurtunatelly, this is not working on Ipad ... 
So i would like integrate a toolbar button above the keyboard like google doc or Word for their mobile app.

Do you know a pluggin which can do that ? Thanks a lot about your contribution
I though about cordova-plugin-native-keyboard what do you think about it ?